Is it forbidden to jump in the water from any bank of the international river borders by local immigration in the Golden Triangle?
I read on What are the risks associated with swimming in the Mekong River? (emphasis is mine):

If you are planning to do this at the golden triangle: you need to be a good swimmer: the river is quite wide there. There is also a risk of drifting into Myanmar which is definitely not a great spot to be at the moment. I'm also fairly sure it's forbidden to just jump in the water from any bank of the river by local immigration, but I have no data to back that up, – Hilmar Apr 26 at 15:11

Is it forbidden to jump in the water from any bank of the international river borders by local immigration in the Golden Triangle? (any bank = can be in Laos, Myanmar or Thailand).

If anything, this should only be a comment asking Hilmar to justify the claims that he made in his comment.

@PeterM No, because comments are ephemeral on SE.

Comments being ephemeral have nothing to do with what I said.  Your question is akin to Hilmar saying something to you in the street, and then you get on your rooftop and yell "Is Hilmar right?".  Except you are yelling at everyone except Hilmar - the very person who could attest to the veracity of his statement.

@PeterM Hilmar already stated they weren't fully sure about it. Why would asking them again help? And I have to mention their name due to the content license.

I dunno, maybe to find out the basis for why they made that statement?  The very statement that you included in your own answer to your own question.

@PeterM what don't you understand in "but I have [no] data to back that up"? (or maybe you didn't realize that the missing no was a typo?)

I don't care what Hilmar said or didn't say.   Hilmar is a real person who is active on here.  You can have a discussion with Hilmar anytime you want about the statements that they made - but you choose not to do that.  However, that should be the very first thing you do before turning it into a public question.

@PeterM Hilmar already wrote "but I have [no] data to back that up". What else do you want them to say?

I have no idea what they will say as I am not Hilmar.  And you have not asked Hilmar. Which is my entire point.

@PeterM "I have [no] data to back that up" means they have no data to back that up aka they don't know,  hence my question here.
